# Simple yet tricky trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

This might seem silly to ask, but how can I solve a trigonometry problem for the unknown $h$ in the form of: 
$x + 45 = h/\tan 30$ and 
$x = h/\tan 50$

Comment: I assume everything here is in degrees? You might want to make note of that; often angles are expressed in radians.

Comment: the 30 and 50 are the only ones in degrees..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $h$ is the variable we are solving for, express both equations as functions of $h$:

$$x + 45 = \dfrac h{\tan (30^\circ)} \iff x = \dfrac h{\tan(30^\circ)} - 45\tag{1}$$
$$x = \dfrac h{\tan (50^\circ)}\tag{2}$$

Now, since the right-hand and left-hand sides of the equation are each equal to $x$, they are equal to *each other*. So we have:

$$\dfrac h{\tan(30^\circ)} - 45 =  \dfrac h{\tan (50^\circ)} $$

Now we have an *equation in one variable*, and can solve for $h$. Once you solve for $h$, you can evaluate the tangent of the angles, perhaps using an identity or two?

(Recall that $\tan(45)$ and $\tan(50)$ are constants (have a constant value) - their values do not depend here on $h$ or $x$).

Comment: Thanks for explaining those steps. Could you walk me though how to solve for h? I keep getting stuck..

Comment: How do you solve for $h$ in an equation like $\dfrac h2 - 5 = \dfrac h3$. It's the same process needed here: There is **one** variable: gather like terms, factor out $h$, simplify...

Comment: so: h/tan50 - h/tan30 = 45...then multiply both sides by tan 150?

Comment: Almost: the subtraction  of terms needs to be reversed. Then, factor out the common term: $h$, on the left hand side: $$h(\;?\; - \;?\;) = 45$$

Comment: h(1/tan30 - 1/tan50)= 45 ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Now what do you need to divide each side of the equation by in order to get $h$ on the left hand side by itself?

Comment: Ok so h= 45/(1/tan30 - 1/tan50)...My calculator is giving me 50.39..is that right or did I mess up?

Comment: That's right! (of course, a calculator "rounds"...but you've got it!

Comment: Finally! Could you please help me on another trig problem that I keep banging my head against without success...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424621/confusing-trigonometry-problem